# Hide Navigation Bar but keep the Bar Button

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

[image]In my app, I need the background image to cover the full screen, but I also need a Bar Button on the screen.. So I guess I need to hide/remove the navigation bar(to cover the whole screen with my background image but somehow save the bar button. Is it possible?
EDIT:The grey part(NavigationBar) must be gone. The button(Item) has to stay

Comment: Please post here your code?

Comment: I dont have a code yet..Just started coding, nothing important have been typed in yet

Comment: Honestly, I didn't get what you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

Answer (score 6):

You could make the navigation bar transparent using the following snippet:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Update: Same in Objective-C:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: It says 
"Property 'navigationBar' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'; did you mean 'navigationItem'?"

Comment: Sorry you have to use 'navigationController?.navigationBar'

Answer (score -1):

```
- (IBAction)actionBtn:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d",nv);

    if (nv==0) {

        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=nv;
        nv=1;
    }
    else
    {

 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=nv;
           nv=0;
    }

}
```

try this ....

Comment: When answering please include some explanation as too why this might work.

Answer (score -3):

You should custom your Bar Button without use the system's

Comment: Need to to post comment rather then answer.